# Update query to SQL from php file

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to update a patient's record its saying its complete but its not updating phpmyadmin. When I press save and update button it shows Save was successful. Any Ideas ?

---

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

$id1 = $_POST['PatientID']; //Text box the user searches in

mysql_query("UPDATE PatientRecords SET 
PatientID = '".$_POST['PatientID']."', 
FirstName = '".$_POST['FirstName']."', 
LastName = '".$_POST['LastName']."',
DOB = '".$_POST['DOB']."', 
IDNumber1 = '".$_POST['IDNumber1']."', 
Medication1 = '".$_POST['Medication1']."', 
Medication1Dosage = '".$_POST['Medication1Dosage']."',
IDNumber2 = '".$_POST['IDNumber2']."', 
Medication2 = '".$_POST['Medication2']."', 
Medication2Dosage = '".$_POST['Medication2Dosage']."', 
IDNumber3 = '".$_POST['IDNumber3']."', 
Medication3 = '".$_POST['Medication3']."', 
Medication3Dosage = '".$_POST['Medication3Dosage']."', 
MedicalNotes = '".$_POST['MedicalNotes']."'
WHERE PatientID = '$id1');

echo"Patient Information has been updated successfully";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the "PatientID = '$id1'" exists and is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is confirmed as when I run my "searchpatient" query it displays the correct patient information

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong to begin with. If you're UPDATING an existing row, leave the `VALUES (...` out and end the query after `WHERE PatientID = '$id1'`. If you're INSERTING a new row, use `INSERT table (column, column, ...) VALUES (value, value, ...)` and don't use WHERE.

Comment: And the example code doesn't establish a value for $id1, And once you've fixed the errors then the code will be *very* vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: I have edited query and removed the values however its still not working but giving me a white screen and when i view page source its blank

Comment: You're missing the quote close " in `WHERE PatientID = '$id1');` -> `WHERE PatientID = '$id1'");`

Comment: Its all working now - Thank you guys for your input - Stack overflow rocks